# In Java, how to print positive signs in the numbers?

Tags: javascript, java

Please help me, i have a very simple question here. I would like to know how to print a positive signs in the numbers while using a java code. with C++ i can make it with setiosflags(ios::showpos) and it will print +2,+1,+5,etc.

Comment: If you don't know that Java and JavaScript are different languages, you should probably read a Java tutorial first.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getStringFromIntWithSign(int num) {
    if (num > 0) { 
        return "+"+num; 
    } else {
        return ""+num;
    }
}
```

Tweak to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way<sup>1</sup> to tell Java "globally", or for a particular stream, to format numbers with an explicit sign.

There are various ways to format specific numbers with an explicit sign.  For example:

```
    System.out.println("Number is " + (num > 0 ? "+" : "") + num);
```

The most elegant way is to use the `Formatter` class and the "+" flag; e.g. (indirectly)

```
    System.out.println(String.format("Number is %+d", num));
```

---

<sup>1 - I should qualify that.  In theory you could create and use a funky `Locale` that delivers a custom `NumberFormat` object that formats numbers with an explicit sign.  That would cause *some kinds of i18n message formatting* to "globally" change their behavior ... for all cases where the locale is used.  But it would probably break other things.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the results and show if x > 0, etc.. But i dont know a function in the java library to display only positive integers